# Java Program to load the multiple csv files from HDFS, read column values and load into HBASE?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I am new to big data and hadoop.

I have a requirement where I have to upload 100 csv files with information in it ( ex. People information ie. Name, age, city) to hdfs

and then using a java program to load the csv files from HDFS, read column values and load into HBASE.

Can you please help me ?

Parsing files is fine. But I do not understand how to use java to
load multiple csv files from hdfs to hbase.

Comment: By default, if you use Spark or Pig, for example, and load a HDFS directory of all csv files, they'll all be read with the same schema. Then you just load into hbase using the necessary APIs

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your csv files on HDFS.
So to read the files with java you need to:

- make use of HDFS configuration files, usually can be found in /etc/hadoop/conf directory on the HDFS nodes.
- use hadoop java client libraries.

The code for reading a text file from HDFS might be something like this:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
    
Path file = new Path("/user/username/people-file.csv");
    
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    
FSDataInputStream is = hdfs.open(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is, "UTF-8" ) );
    
String lineRead = br.readLine();
while(lineRead != null) {
    System.out.println(lineRead);
    lineRead = br.readLine();
    //do what ever you need with the line of data, map it into object, add into collection, e.t.c...
}
    
br.close();
hdfs.close();
```

And then when you have your data in memory, you can save it into HBASE. So to save your data into HBASE you need:

- make use of HBASE configuration files, usually can be found in /etc/hbase/conf directory on the HBASE nodes.
- use of hbase java client library

The code for inserting a data into HBASE might be something like this:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));

String tableName = "people";
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));

//you might have similar array after reading the csv files
String[][] people = {
                { "1", "Marcel", "Haddad", "marcel@xyz.com", "M", "26" },
                { "2", "Franklin", "Holtz", "franklin@xyz.com", "M", "24" },
                { "3", "Dwayne", "McKee", "dwayne@xyz.com", "M", "27" },
                { "4", "Rae", "Schroeder", "rae@xyz.com", "F", "31" },
                { "5", "Rosalie", "burton", "rosalie@xyz.com", "F", "25" },
                { "6", "Gabriela", "Ingram", "gabriela@xyz.com", "F", "24" } };

for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    Put person = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(people[i][0]));
    person.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("first"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][1]));
    person.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("last"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][2]));
    person.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("contact_info"), Bytes.toBytes("email"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][3]));
    person.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("personal_info"), Bytes.toBytes("gender"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][4]));
    person.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("personal_info"), Bytes.toBytes("age"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][5]));
    table.put(person);
}

table.close();
connection.close()
```

Note that you need to create table (schema) in HBASE before you will start inserting data, like here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_create_table.htm

Comment: Why not use Spark for this instead?

Comment: Well, the question was about doing it with java, spark of course is another approach.

Comment: But you can use Spark _in Java_, was my point. Then you don't need these lines to load in Hadoop config files and can read/write CSV to HBase using SparkSQL pretty easily

Comment: yes, it is a valid point

Comment: Spark is not the requirement so cannot use it.